# MySQL Added additional columns to my table, how to update table

Tags: mysql

How can I load data from a file without replacing the existing columns but just adding missing values? For example if I already had a table and one of the rows would be

```
Id: 25, username: john, password: #hash
```

And then I add new columns `bday`, `height`, `surname` to my database and populate a `csv file` with them.

Is it possible to load those into a file without changing the `id's` of the users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is based on import the data in a new temporary table  and then perform the update on the orginal table for the column you need  join the rows between the 2 tables

eg .

```
table1 (id, key1, col1, col2_added) 

table_temp(id, key1, col1, col2)
```

once you imported the  files in table_temp you can

```
update table1
join table_temp = table1.key = table_temp.key
set col2_add = col2;
```